# Java assignment of static variable++

Tags: java, variables, static, variable-assignment

When I assign the value++ of a static int to another int, it is performing the assignments in an order that doesn't seem to follow the order of operations for Java. Shouldn't it do the `++` before the `=`?

```
public class Book
{
  private int id;
  private static int lastID = 0;

  public Book ()
  {
    id=lastID++;
  }
}
```

In the first book I construct, the id is 0. Shouldn't it be 1 since `lastID++` should happen first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't it do the ++ before the =?

--> Yes `++` is evaluated first as below :

Your expression :

```
id = lastID++;
```

is equivalent to following expression

```
temp = lastId;    // temp is 0
lastID = lastID + 1;  // increament, lastId becomes 1
id = temp;   // assign old value i.e. 0
```

So you have `id as 0`, you should use, pre-increament operator(++) in this case as :

```
public class Book
{
  private int id;
  private static int lastID = 0;

  public Book ()
  {
    id = ++lastID; // pre-increament
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your are using the postfix `++` operator. This will increment after the variable is used (in your case is assignment).

If you want to increment before assignment use this

```
id = ++lastID;
```

This is known as the prefix `++` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`lastID++;` uses **post-increment** operator, as the name suggests you use the current value of `lastID` firstly (which is assigned to `id`), then the value of `lastID` incremented by 1.

Answer (score 1):

`lastID++` returns the value that `lastId` had before the increment.

If you want `id` to be also incremented, that is to get the value of `lastID` after the increment, use

```
id = ++lastID;
```

Answer (score 1):

No. `id = lastID++` will affect `lastID` to `id`, and then increment `lastID`.

Try

```
id = ++lastID;
```

which will do the opposite (increment `lastID`, and affect the new value of `lastID` to `id`).

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languagues you can do ++var and var++.

++var immediately increments the value of the variable, while var++ while increment the value of the variable, but return the **previous** value.